# Dynamic Styles in Fluent UI v9/ Fluent UI 2

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am trying to pass dynamic CSS styles in html tags using Fluent UI v9 or Fluent UI 2.

In the previous versions I could use the styles prop and wrap it in a function where we pass the props and accordingly modify the styles dynamically. With the new fluent UI the styles prop does not exist and contains the new hook style implementation of adding CSS styles and I cannot wrap it in a function as being a hook. Can anyone help if there is a way to have dynamic styles other than overriding the styles with a new style based on precedence.